# Linux debian dependency issues and wine installation

Tags: debian, software-installation, dependencies, wine

I am trying to install wine since several days but I cannot succes I have so  MANY dependencies issues when I try to install a missing dependency it requires another dependency etc .. infinite circle !

so there is what I have did so far:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

done

```
apt-get update
```

done

```
apt-get install wine-development
```

fail :

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-development : Depends: wine64-development (>= 1.7.29-4) but it is not going to be installed or
                             wine32-development (>= 1.7.29-4)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I tried

```
apt-get install wine
```

Which worked ! but something is wrong because it cannot execute any executable files...

```
wine: Bad EXE format for Z:\home\***\Downloads\LTspiceIV.exe.
```

I have also tried

```
apt-get install wine-*
```

which give me these dependencies issues:

```
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
> state information... Done Note, selecting 'wine64-unstable' for regex
> 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'wine64-bin' for regex 'wine-*' Note,
> selecting 'libwine-openal' for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting
> 'wine32-dev-tools' for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'libwine-dev'
> for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'libwine-gecko-dbg-2.21' for regex
> 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'libwine-gecko-dbg-2.24' for regex 'wine-*'
> Note, selecting 'libwine-capi' for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting
> 'wine-utils' for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'q4wine-unstable' for
> regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'wine64-development-preloader' for
> regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'wine64-development' for regex 'wine-*'
> Note, selecting 'libkwineffects1abi5' for regex 'wine-*' Note,
> selecting 'wine64-tools' for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting
> 'libwine-ldap' for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'libwine-oss' for
> regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'libwine-gphoto2' for regex 'wine-*'
> Note, selecting 'libwine-sane' for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting
> 'libwine-alsa' for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'wine' for regex
> 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'q4wine' for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting
> 'winetricks' for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'wine32-unstable' for
> regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'wine64-development-tools' for regex
> 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'libwine-development-dbg' for regex 'wine-*'
> Note, selecting 'shiki-wine-theme' for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting
> 'wine32' for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'libwine-development-dev'
> for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'wine-development' for regex
> 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'wine64' for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting
> 'libwine-cms' for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'libwine' for regex
> 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'libwine-bin' for regex 'wine-*' Note,
> selecting 'libwine-development' for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting
> 'wine32-development' for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'wine-binfmt'
> for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'libwine-gl' for regex 'wine-*'
> Note, selecting 'wine1.2' for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'wine1.3'
> for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'wine-unstable' for regex 'wine-*'
> Note, selecting 'wine1.4' for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'wine1.5'
> for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'wine1.6' for regex 'wine-*' Note,
> selecting 'wine1.7' for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'arc-wine' for
> regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'wine32-development-tools' for regex
> 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'wine-64-dev-tools' for regex 'wine-*' Note,
> selecting 'wine64-dev-tools' for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting
> 'wine32-tools' for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting
> 'gnome-wine-icon-theme' for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'twine' for
> regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting 'libwine-gecko-2.21' for regex 'wine-*'
> Note, selecting 'libwine-gecko-2.24' for regex 'wine-*' Note,
> selecting 'wine-bin' for regex 'wine-*' Note, selecting
> 'wine32-tools:i386' instead of 'wine32-tools' Note, selecting
> 'wine32:i386' instead of 'wine32' Note, selecting
> 'wine32-development-tools:i386' instead of 'wine32-development-tools'
> Note, selecting 'wine32-development:i386' instead of
> 'wine32-development' libwine is already the newest version. libwine
> set to manually installed. wine is already the newest version. wine64
> is already the newest version. libwine-gecko-2.21 is already the
> newest version. libwine-gecko-2.21 set to manually installed. Some
> packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested
> an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution
> that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved
> out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the
> situation:
> 
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  wine32:i386 :
> Depends: libwine:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: libfreetype6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                Recommends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed  wine32-development:i386 : Depends:
> libwine-development:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                            Depends: libfreetype6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                            Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                            Recommends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed  wine32-development-tools:i386 : Depends:
> gcc:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                                  Depends: libgettextpo0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                                  Depends: libwine-development-dev:i386 (= 1.7.29-4) but it is not going to be installed  wine32-tools:i386 :
> Depends: libwine:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>                      Depends: libwine-dev:i386 (= 1.6.2-20) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held
> broken packages.
```

I have also tried to remove the not working wine that I have installed before, by doing "apt-get purge wine*" ... and it also removed several gnome related things like gnome settings menu etc ..and also plenty of stuff, I reinstalled everything but I'd like to know why it did that....????

I have also tried to install the missing dependencies, but they require other dependencies.

And lastly I tried the same commands using `aptitude` which tells me that it can solve my issues if I accept to remove gnome and several other plenty of stuff ...

So there it is, I am totally lost with these dependency issues what should I do ?

EDIT: ok .. I was trying to install one of the dependencies ... and apt-get just removed my whole gnome and grub !
So, I am gonna reinstall DEBIAN, for the 5th time in the month, nice

Answer (score 0):

had very similar issue and errors installing Wine-development today.

After refusing (`n`) aptitude's first proposal, which was more or less "uninstall all the system", it proposed to downgrade a few packages (`libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev locales`). Accepted the proposal (`y`), and wine's installation succeeded.

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to explain how to get `aptitude` to "downgrade a few packages", so it's essentially not reproducible. Providing step-by-step instructions would be helpful.

Comment: You must refuse the first proposal (press `N` key) and accept the second (`Y` key).. of course it strongly depends on the environment, but aptitude's second proposal was much more sensible, and solved the same problem at the same time, for me.